# responsivefilemanager upload path in localhost

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce-4

I'm using  [responsivefilemanager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) for file upload in tinymce. But in settings config file I have problem.

install and server details:

```
base url : h**p://localhost (xammp)

folder : /user/

upload folder : /user/uploads/files/

thumbs folder : /user/uploads/files/thumbs/

Install filemanager: /user/templates/admin/js/filemanager/
```

Now, I set config file like this:

```
 $base_url =
        // Get HTTP/HTTPS
        ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && !in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']),array('off','no'))) ? 'https' : 'http').
        '://'.
        // Get domain portion
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // DON'T TOUCH (base url (only domain) of site (without final /)).
    $upload_dir = '/user/uploads/files/'; // path from base_url to base of upload folder (with start and final /)
    $current_path = '../../files/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (with final /)
    //thumbs folder can't put inside upload folder
    $thumbs_base_path = '../../thumbs/';
```

But This not worked and won't upload/create folder ....

How can fix/edit config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Replace:

```
$current_path = '../../files/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (with final /)
    //thumbs folder can't put inside upload folder
$thumbs_base_path = '../../thumbs/';
```

With :

```
$current_path = '../../../../uploads/files/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (with final /)
//thumbs folder can't put inside upload folder
$thumbs_base_path = '../../../../uploads/files/thumbs/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to thumbs folder (with final /)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for Localhost / Real Host

$vDomsDev = array('localhost', 'localhost:80');

if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $vDomsDev)){

```
    //////////////////////////////
    // DEVELOPMENT
    /////////////////////////////

    $dominioSeg = $dominio = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/LOCALFOLDER/';


}else{

    //////////////////////////////
    // Real Serv
    //////////////////////////////

    if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.mywebpage.com'){
        $dominio = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $dominioSeg = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    }else{
        $dominioSeg = $dominio = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    }
}
```

$config = array(

```
'base_url' => $dominioSeg,
'upload_dir' => '/uploads/images/',
'current_path' => '../../../uploads/images/'
```